# What does the assembly instruction 'REPNE SCAS BYTE PTR ES:[EDI]'?

Tags: assembly, ollydbg

I disassembled a file with OllyDbg and it had the following instruction:

```
REPNE SCAS BYTE PTR ES:[EDI]
```

What does that exactly mean ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The `SCAS` instruction is used to scan a string (`SCAS` = SCan A String). It compares the content of the accumulator (`AL`, `AX`, or `EAX`) against the current value pointed at by `ES:[EDI]`.

When used together with the `REPNE` prefix (*REPeat while Not Equal*), `SCAS` scans the string searching for the first string element which is equal to the value in the accumulator.

The Intel manual (Vol. 1, p.231) says:

> The SCAS instruction subtracts the destination string element from the contents of the EAX, AX, or AL register (depending on operand length) and updates the status flags according to the results. The string element and register contents are not modified. The following “short forms” of the SCAS instruction specify the operand length: SCASB (scan byte string), SCASW (scan word string), and SCASD (scan doubleword string).

So, basically, this instruction scan a string and look for the same character than the one stored in `EAX`. It won't touch any registers other than ECX (counter) and EDI (address) but the status flags according to the results.

Comment: The value pointed by EAX, or the value of EAX? Also, what accumulators does it update? what should look after a REPNE SCAS ?

Comment: The value of EAX and pointed at by ES:[EDI]. The address where the string differ from the character stored in the accumulator is the one currently stored in `ES:[EDI]`.

Comment: Shouldn't a REPNE SCAS be repeat until a match of the value of EAX is found? So i thought it should be "look for a character that **is the same** from the one stored in EAX."?

Comment: @guestme: Yes. Sorry, I did write the opposite of what I meant. I edit the text.

Comment: @perror: your pseudo-code lacks support for the direction flag, which makes it slightly misleading.

Comment: @peterferrie: I have to admit that I do not trust this pseudocode at all... I would better remove it.

Comment: perror explained the instruction really well. I thought I'd add that the instruction(along with few that follow) probably computes the length of the string.

Comment: @dnivra: but that's not all it can do.  Specifically, repnz scasb is the equivalent of memchr().